# Does CABasicAnimation runs in the main or background thread by default

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, swift5, cabasicanimation

This is more a conceptual query than coding. I have a custom activity indicator, a custom view. The only public API, the user will have is the `init(onFrame frame: CGRect)`, `startAnimating()` and `stopAnimating()`.

So, I want to know in the `startAnimating` method, should I create a thread whether main or DispatchQoS to run the animation.

Also, if I don't put the animation code in a thread, will it be automatically running on main thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All communication with a UIView must be on the main thread. All Core Animation is automatically performed on a background thread. So do not do any explicit multithreading in connection with CABasicAnimation.